# What does the following ldd output mean?

Tags: linker, ldd

As I know,
ldd output normally looks like `SHARED_LIBRARY => location`.

But `liblz.so.1` and `libzstd.so.1` below don't seem to be so.

```
ldd librdkafka.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffde7484000)
        liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f97c8953000)     
        libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f97c8420000)    
        libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007f97c8206000)
        libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f97c7f99000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f97c7bb4000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f97c799e000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f97c7799000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f97c757c000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f97c7374000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f97c6fdf000)
```

What is the meaning of this type of output?

Comment: What OS did this happen on? What version of GLIBC?

Answer (score -1):

Psychic debugging: data and packet are the parameters of MPU6050::dmpGetAccel, and you are trying to combine four bytes into a word.

You need to do your arithmetic in uint32_ts, not uint8_ts, otherwise you always overflow the values.

Change all the lines of the form

```
data[n] = ((packet[m] << 24) + (packet[m+1] << 16) + (packet[m+2] << 8) + packet[m+3]);
```

to

```
data[n] = ((uint32_t{ packet[m] } << 24) + (uint32_t{ packet[m+1] } << 16) + (uint32_t{ packet[m+2] } << 8) + uint32_t{ packet[m+3] });
```